# bootstrap - hamburger navigation not stacking vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, hamburger-menu

So I was making a simple responsive navigation. The problem is that for mobiles, the hamburger menu list items do not stack vertically. Also, for regular desktop, the Register dropdown on clicking moves down for some weird reason. I am stuck on it since some hours. Would really appreciate any help..

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #2B74A8;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #2B74A8;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #2B74A8;
}
* {
  max-width: 1280px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: visible;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav {
  background-color: #3FAFFF;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  margin-top: 170px;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #2B74A8;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.nav.navbar-right {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FDFDFD;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
  float: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #FDFDFD;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "SourceSansPro-Light";
  top: 12.5px;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  text-transform: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.required {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "SourceSansPro-Light";
  color: #3FAFFF;
  word-spacing: 10px;
}

body .inputArea {
  width: 267px;
  height: 44px;
  word-spacing: 10px;
  background-color: #2B74A8;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "SourceSansPro-Light";
}

.submit {
  width: 130px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "SourceSansPro-Light";
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #3FAFFF;
  background-image: none;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}


/*Media Queries*/

select.nav-select.form-control {
  display: none;
}

nav.navbar.navbar-default {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.registerForm {
  cursor: pointer;
  word-spacing: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #3FAFFF;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  text-shadow: none;
}

.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #5E6E8F;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2em;
  }
  .center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:active,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:visited {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.form-inline .form-group {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.inputForm {
  word-spacing: 10px;
  height: 65px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #3FAFFF;
}

.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #3FAFFF;
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #3FAFFF;
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #3FAFFF;
}

body input {
  border-color: transparent !important;
  border: none;
}

.glyphicon {
  top: 1.25em;
  right: 4.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <select class="nav-select form-control">
    <option class="" value="/fundamentals">- Fundamentals</option>
    <option class="" value="/html">- HTML</option>
    <option class="" value="/stylesheets">- Stylesheets</option>
    <option class="" value="/javascript">- JavaScript</option>
    <option class="" value="/php">- PHP</option>
    <option class="" value="/tutorials">- Tutorials</option>
    <option class="" value="/register">- Register</option>
  </select>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="height: 1px;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/fundamentals/" target="_self">Fundamentals</a></li>
          <li><a href="/html/" target="_self">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="/stylesheets/" target="_self">Stylesheets</a></li>
          <li><a href="/javaScript/" target="_self">JavaScript</a></li>
          <li><a href="/php/" target="_self">PHP</a></li>
          <li><a href="/tutorials/" target="_self">Tutorials</a></li>

          <ul class="nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse" class="registerForm">Register
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="collapse" id="demo" style="background-color: #2B74A8;">
                <div class="form-group inputForm">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <form class="form-inline">
                      <label class="required">* required </label>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control inputArea" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name *">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control inputArea" id="email" placeholder="Email *">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control inputArea" id="phn" placeholder="Phone Number *">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rossp92/4rgyqpry/1/)

Comment: have you tried to modified it? or change with your own css?

Comment: yes I tried. No luck yet

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex to do this, it's a bit tricky but you can find it in here [all about flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

and these are the css code i made for you

```
.myOwnHeader{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;

  align-items:center; 
}

.myOwnBurger{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  margin-right:25px;
}
```

apply those css to theese dives

```
<div class="navbar-header myOwnHeader">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed myOwnBurger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the width of the li is not set to 100% on mobile devices.

Considering the given markup and the existing styles.

I've come up with this - https://jsfiddle.net/vncnttejas/fenta9wo/8/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #5E6E8F;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul.nav.navbar-nav > li {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3FAFFF;
    height: inherit;
    border-top: 1px dotted white;
  }
  #demo.collapse.in {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
  }
  .nav.navbar-right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav.navbar-right > li.dropdown {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2em;
  }
  .center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:active,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:visited {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```